# Paraboloid defined on a rectangle, finding critical points

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima, hessian-matrix

I'm having trouble with a problem regarding finding critical points of a paraboloid defined on a rectangle. The problem is:

Consider the portion of the paraboloid $f(x,y)=16-x^2-y^2$ defined on the rectangle $R=[-1,2] x [-3,4]$.

I'm trying to find any critical points of the paraboloid on the **interior** of R, relative maxes along each side of R (level curves) where x or y is a constant, and finally identify the global max and mins of f(x,y) on R and where they occur.

I tried with the Hessian determinant but I'm not sure if that's quite right. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 1):

with $$f(x,y)=16-x^2-y^2$$ we get
$$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial x}=-2x$$ and $$\frac{\partial f(x,y)}{\partial y}=-2y$$ and now you must Control the sides of your rectangle.

Comment: Could you explain what you mean by control the sides of the rectangle?